# Why my Dockerfile causes error at Docker Hub?

Tags: haskell, docker

I write following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV PATH /root/.local/bin:$PATH
ENV LTS lts-11.3


RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y upgrade && \
  apt-get -y install curl git openmpi-doc openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev && \
  curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh && \
  stack update && \
  stack upgrade && \
  stack install --resolver $LTS c2hs QuickCheck array attoparsec containers directory hspec optparse-applicative repa split text time vector && \
  stack install --resolver $LTS --extra-include-dirs=/usr/lib/openmpi/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/lib/openmpi/lib haskell-mpi-1.4.0 && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD ["bash"]
```

And autobuild it on Docker Hub:

https://hub.docker.com/r/masterq/fdb/builds/b63fjdgpbcewabgbpfpugjh/

But it causes an error report "Unexpected error".
However I can pull the image:

```
$ docker pull masterq/fdb:feature_dockerhub
feature_dockerhub: Pulling from masterq/fdb
22dc81ace0ea: Already exists
1a8b3c87dba3: Already exists
91390a1c435a: Already exists
07844b14977e: Already exists
b78396653dae: Already exists
2069ab170dd3: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:47ec2ba2d2df6a33bbca0208348774fcbd431f0d544a5cfe46f170d93f08c7fd
Status: Downloaded newer image for masterq/fdb:feature_dockerhub
```

Why does Docker Hub maintain my Dockerfile as error?

Best regards,

Comment: https://support.docker.com/

Comment: I don't see any errors in the log. How is your autobuild configured?

Comment: My public repo also causes same error:

https://github.com/master-q/docker4fdb
https://hub.docker.com/r/masterq/docker4fdb/builds/bcuvzfebhz4nzu7xkdvpjie/

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/masterq/40553104844/ < autobuild configured

Comment: My 3rd build got success. Is it fixed at Docker Hub side? https://hub.docker.com/r/masterq/fdb/builds/bocfoqxtwklwjevrfrj7ebd/